# How to split a string in combo block quota EX: [ text ] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm a newbie in jQuery and i don't know how to do my homework, pls help me !

i have a String EX: this is my text, press here.

Now i put in o block character : [here]

how can a take slipt string and get text in [ ] into variable 'done'?

thankyou !

---

my HTML here:

```
<div id="quotacontain">
   <p>this is demo [ string ]</p>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var temp = $("#quotacontain p").text();
var done = '';
```

now i want get text in syntax [ ] and get into variable 'done'. But i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: Show us some code. Even something like:

var EX = "press here";
...

Using split is very straight forward in javascript but it is difficult to discern your situation from the description you gave.

Comment: oh, thanks. my HTML here:
<div id="quotacontain">
   <p>this is demo [ string ] .</p>
</div>

Jquery :
var done='';
var temptext= $('#quotacontain p').text();

now i want get text in syntax [ ] and get into variable 'done'. But i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some documentation that might help:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split)

Comment: Thanks you !. i found my work in link Regular Expressions !. you save my day :). Thank you so much !